# Polymorphism WCF deserialization doesn't work

Tags: c#, json, wcf, deserialization, known-types

I have  created the following classes. one base class IObject and 2 derived classes A and B.

```
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
[KnownType(typeof(A))]
[DataContract(Name = "IObject")]
public class IObject
{
}

[DataContract(Name="A")]
public class A : IObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string s1 { get; set; }     // Tag Name as it will be presented to the user

}

[DataContract(Name="B")]
public class B : IObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string s2 { get; set; }         

}
```

I have also created the following Service:

```
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(B))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(A))]
    public void GetR(IObject obj)
    {

        B other = (B)obj;
    }
```

What i want to do is get an instance of A or B but i don't know which one i will get so i expect to get an IObject and cast it later to either A or B as shown in the example i put.

What happens when i send a json string containing s2 string is that i get IObject instance and not B instance.
What is wrong with the code?

Example of the client i'm using :

```
    var url = serviceURL;
    var data = {s2: "Data"};
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Edited: I have uploaded an example code to gitHub at the following link:
https://github.com/AlgoEitan/27588144

The client there is a c# client (I've tried it with both c# and javascript - web browser client)

Comment: Are you using `DataContractJsonSerializer`, Json.NET or `JavaScriptSerializer`?

Comment: I've tried 2 different clients:
1. using a web browser like the code I put above.
2. I tried a c# client where I tried JavaScriptSerializer and after that didn't work i tried DataContractJsonSerializer

Both ways didn't make a difference - i still got an IObject instance.

Comment: What happens if you change `IObject` to an `interface`?

Comment: interface doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataContractJsonSerializer` has a [specific format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) in which it stores hints about known type information for polymorphic types, which one can discover with a bit of testing.  I copied and pasted your classes as-is, and created the following test code:

```
public static class DataContractJsonSerializerPolymorphismTest
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var a1 = new A() { s1 = "A" };
        var b1 = new B() { s2 = "B" };

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IObject));

        var jsona1 = DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetJson(a1, serializer);
        var jsonb1 = DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetJson(b1, serializer);

        Debug.WriteLine(jsona1);
        Debug.WriteLine(jsonb1);

        var newa1 = DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetObject<IObject>(jsona1, serializer);

        Debug.Assert(newa1.GetType() == a1.GetType()); // No assert
    }
}
```

With that, the following JSON was created:

```
{"__type":"A:#Tile.DataContractJsonSerializerPolymorphism","s1":"A"}
{"__type":"B:#Tile.DataContractJsonSerializerPolymorphism","s2":"B"}
```

Where `Tile.DataContractJsonSerializerPolymorphism` happens to be the name of the CLR namespace in my test application.  So, as you can see, the known type information got tucked away in this extra JSON property `__type`.  Now, if you were using  `DataContractJsonSerializerHelper` in your client also, you would never know this, because communication would just work.  But you are using `JSON.stringify()` which does not have this logic.  So, you may have to manually add the `"__type":"DataContractName:DataContractNamespace"` property on the client side.

More about the format for polymorphic types can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx).  (I only tracked this documentation down after finding the hidden `__type` parameter, which gave me an extra Google search term.)

FYI, here is the helper class I used with the test code:

```
public static class DataContractJsonSerializerHelper
{
    private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
    }

    public static string GetJson<T>(T obj, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer) where T : class
    {
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(memory, obj);
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetJson<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetJson(obj, serializer);
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string json) where T : class
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetObject<T>(json, serializer);
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer) where T : class
    {
        T obj = null;
        using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(json))
        {
            obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I was using the DataContractJsonSerializer (For my c# client) and it didn't add the __type.
I had to force it to add type to json with: EmitTypeInformation.Always